# JQuery getting value from each dynamic row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, each

I am trying to get the values from a series of dynamic divs to wirte to a db.

My html for the divs is as follows....

```
<div class='doc_holder_list'>
<p class='right'> (Delete [<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='appended'>X</a>])</p>
<p><span class='red2' data-file_id='10'>File 10</span></p>
<p class='file_desc1a'>File Description 10</p>
<p class='file_ins1a'>File Notes 7</p>
</div>
<div class='doc_holder_list'>
<p class='right'> (Delete [<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='appended'>X</a>])</p>
<p><span class='red2' data-file_id='34'>File 7</span></p>
<p class='file_desc1a'>File Description 7</p>
<p class='file_ins1a'>File Notes 7</p>
</div> etc....
```

My JQuery of which is failing...

```
$.each($('.doc_holder_list'),function(){
            var get_file_id=$('.red2').data('file_id');
            get_files+=get_file_id+"|";
            alert(get_files);
        });
```

At present this is trying to return only the file id in the data attribute. Eventually I want to drag the descriptions out as well for each instance of the doc_holder_list div.

Comment: On a separate note, will this system be publicly available? If so I would avoid having your file IDs so easily readable and editable. Obviously you'll need to heavily clean and check the data you receive server-side, but it would be very easy for someone to change a file_id which might completely confuse your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to localise your search at each level, `$('.red')` will search and find all the `.red` on your page, which is not what you want at that point - you want to find the `.red` within `.doc_holder_list`:

*(Please note both the following methods will probably only work if you also implement my recommendation below about using `$('').each()` rather than `$.each()`)*

```
/// this allows you to search within an existing jQuery selection
/// as you are within an each() "this" will refer to .doc_holder_list
get_file_id=$(this).find('.red2')
```

or

```
/// this defines the 'context' of where your jQuery search will occur
/// as you are within an each() "this" will refer to .doc_holder_list
get_file_id=$('.red2', this)
```

Either of the above should sort your problem...

Also, rather than:

```
$.each($('.doc_holder_list'),function(){
```

It would be cleaner to write:

```
$('.doc_holder_list').each(function(){
  ....
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems to be working. I did try a similar method to what you describe but I put 'this' before the class selector as in $(this, '.red2'). My newbie error :)